# Embedded Google calendar not displaying unless logged into Google account

Tags: iframe, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to embed my Google calendar using an iframe in a small website that I am making, but it seems I can only see the calendar when I am logged into a Google account. If I log out of my Google profiles and then open the page, I just get an empty iframe.

I know it's possible because I've seen other websites display calendars when I'm not logged onto Google, but looking at their code I can't see any difference to what I've got.

I'm getting the error:

```
Refused to display 'googleCalendarLinkHere' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.
```

Comment: Hello, Yes stupidly enough I had not set it to be viewed publicly... Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set your calendar to be publicly viewable.

Comment: Ya thats was the problem... Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. You can click the checkmark to the left to accept this as your answer. Whenever you accept an answer, the answerer gets fifteen points and you get two points (as an incentive to accept answers).

Comment: Also, if you take the [Stack Overflow tour (click here)](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) then you will learn more about how to use Stack Overflow and earn the bronze badge "informed".

Comment: ok I will thanks, was my first question Ive asked on here so didnt know I could accept an answer like that.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Feel free to ask and **answer** questions. I learn a lot from answering (or trying to answer) questions.

Comment: I will try answer some in time, but at the moment Im at the stage of looking for answers as google calendar is giving me some trouble at the moment! But Ill get there