# Google Calendar iframe does not display when logged out of Google account

Tags: iframe, google-calendar-api

I'm having a similar problem to this: [Embedded Google calendar not displaying unless logged into Google account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28634419/embedded-google-calendar-not-displaying-unless-logged-into-google-account)

I embedded an iframe of my Google Calendar onto my webpage, but it only displays when I am actively logged into my Google account. I have the calendar set to be publicly viewable, but the problem persists.

Comment: Have you set the calendar to public first then copied the embed link?  You can also add steps how you did it to provide a more vivid picture.

Comment: @noogui Yes, I set the calendar to public before I copied the embed link. This is the page where the iframe is embedded, it's completely blank unless I log into my Google account: https://gatewayinteract.org/calendar/